# Socket.io working on desktop safari & chrome, but not mobile

Tags: android, ios, iphone, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to establish communication between server and html5 client and everything is working fine on desktop and safari on iPhone simulator. The client fails to establish connection though when I try to run it from any iOS or even android device.

Using web inspector, I was unable to output console error on my ios7 device, but managed to get a list of resource with an item under XHR attempting to connect to the server ip address and fails after about 2 to 3 minutes (turns red)

My iOS device is iOS 7.03 (iPhone 4), and I'm using node v0.10.21, and socket.io v0.9.16
I'm also using ip addresses to connect so I'm not sure if there is a same domain restriction that applies

The following are the relevant parts from the client:

```
<script src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket =  io.connect("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:port");

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("connected");
}

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("disconencted");
}

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log("rcved:"+ data*emphasized text*);
}
```

server

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(12321).set('log level', 0);
var ConnectionHandler = require('./handler.js');


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
new ConnectionHandler(socket);
});
```

Might I also point out that when I enable full logging on server side, no connection are attempt for a connection is made from mobile devices, just the desktop devices and iOS simulator.

Any suggestions on a fix or how to pursue a solution to this problem is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a firewall issue :|

Desktop PC was on VPN, mobile phone was not
Which explains this issue

I feel dumb, but I'll leave it here in case it helps someone check for this very same issue

Comment: What did you do ? Set up a VPN for your phone?

Comment: If this resolved your question you can mark your response as the correct one, so that the question appears resolved for people looking for this issue.